# Excel formula lookup to power query table causes column reference to change

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery, xlookup

I am trying to lookup the data in column Z of my power query results using the following basic XLOOKUP formula, however Excel auto adjusts the column reference each time I refresh the data. In the example below, the reference to column Z changed to AB. I'm at a loss on how to fix this.

=IF(XLOOKUP('ATB Request Form'!$C2&'ATB Request Form'!$D2,EzeModeling!$N:$N&EzeModeling!$O:$O,**EzeModeling!$AB:$AB**,0,0)=0,"",XLOOKUP('ATB Request Form'!$C2&'ATB Request Form'!$D2,EzeModeling!$N:$N&EzeModeling!$O:$O,**EzeModeling!$AB:$AB**,0,0))

Answer (score 1):

Use structured table references in your formula, not column letters.

```
=IF(XLOOKUP('ATB Request Form'!$C2&'ATB Request Form'!$D2,EzeModeling!$N:$N&EzeModeling!$O:$O,Table1[Column Z Header],0,0)=0,"",XLOOKUP('ATB Request Form'!$C2&'ATB Request Form'!$D2,EzeModeling!$N:$N&EzeModeling!$O:$O,Table1[Column Z Header],0,0))
```

You can also use LET to make this more efficient and easier to understand:

```
=LET(lookupResult,XLOOKUP('ATB Request Form'!$C2&'ATB Request Form'!$D2,EzeModeling!$N:$N&EzeModeling!$O:$O,Table1[Column Z Header],0,0),IF(lookupResult=0,"",lookupresult))
```